# SQL Server - Values multiplied by join

Tags: sql, sql-server

having a bit of trouble with this one...

The summed, grouped column TotalStoreVisitTime is being multiplied due to the left join further down. I have attempted sub-queries but cannot successfully implement. Someone else I have spoken with has attempted this using cursors etc. but it seems over complicated.

```
SELECT t1.StaffName                 AS "Staff Name" 
       ,MIN(t1.ManagerName)         AS "Manager" 
       ,t1.Name                     AS "Store" 
       ,t1.StartDate                AS "Date" 
       ,SUM(t1.TotalStoreVisitTime) AS "Total Store Time" -- this value gets multiplied by the LEFT JOIN further down.
       ,SUM(t2.TotalClientTime)     AS "Total Client Time"  
FROM   t1 
       LEFT JOIN t2 
              ON t1.StaffName = 
                 t2.StaffName 
                 AND t1.Name = t2.Store 
                 AND t1.StartDate = 
                     t2.StartDate 
WHERE  t1.StartDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) 
GROUP  BY t1.StaffName 
          ,t1.Name
          ,t1.StartDate 
ORDER  BY t1.StartDate DESC;
```

The output is as follows:

```
| Staff Name |  Manager   |   Store    |   Date    | Total Store Time | Total Client Time |
|------------|------------|------------|-----------|------------------|-------------------|
| John Smith | Jane Smith | Test Store | 6/07/2017 |        25.899996 |          4.033332 |
```

The desired output is this (i.e. with Total Store Time just summing the rows from t1 and not being multiplied by the number of rows in t2):

```
| Staff Name |  Manager   |   Store    |   Date    | Total Store Time | Total Client Time |
|------------|------------|------------|-----------|------------------|-------------------|
| John Smith | Jane Smith | Test Store | 6/07/2017 |         4.316666 |          4.033332 |
```

Comment: Provide schema of two tables and the sample data... To analyse further...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub-query is good to go:

```
SELECT t1.StaffName     AS "Staff Name" 
   ,MIN(t1.ManagerName) AS "Manager" 
   ,t1.Name             AS "Store" 
   ,t1.StartDate        AS "Date" 
   ,(SELECT SUM(t3.TotalStoreVisitTime)
     FROM TableA t3
     WHERE t1.StaffName = t3.StaffName 
       AND t1.Name = t3.Name 
       AND t1.StartDate = t3.StartDate) AS "Total Store Time" -- compare with primary key
   ,SUM(t2.TotalClientTime)     AS "Total Client Time"
FROM TableA  t1
LEFT JOIN TableB t2
ON t1.StaffName =t2.StaffName
AND t1.Name = t2.Store
AND t1.StartDate = t2.StartDate
WHERE t1.StartDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
GROUP BY t1.StaffName, t1.Name, t1.StartDate
ORDER BY t1.StartDate DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with the sub-query. It turns out that using the sub-query for the TotalStoreVisitTime then multiplied the sum of TotalClientTime by the number of rows in the Left table. To fix this I used another sub-query to select the sum of TotalClientTime (using t4.) then got rid of the LEFT JOIN further down.

Answer (score 0):

You need to aggregate before the `join`.  I think this might work:

```
SELECT t1.StaffName                 AS "Staff Name" ,
       t1.Manager                  AS "Manager", 
       t1.Name                     AS "Store" ,
       t1.StartDate                AS "Date" ,
       t1.tot AS "Total Store Time", -- this value gets multiplied by the LEFT JOIN further down.
       SUM(t2.TotalClientTime)     AS "Total Client Time"  
FROM (SELECT t1.StaffName, t1.Name, t1.StartDate,
             SUM(t1.TotalStoreVisitTime) as tot,
             MIN(t1.ManagerName) as manager
      FROM t1
      WHERE t1.StartDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) 
     ) t1 LEFT JOIN
     t2
     ON t1.StaffName = t2.StaffName AND
        t1.Name = t2.Store AND
        t1.StartDate = t2.StartDate 
GROUP BY t1.StaffName, t1.Name, t1.StartDate 
ORDER BY t1.StartDate DESC;
```